Is there any reason to use g_strdup from GLib over strdup from the C standard library?
I've been working on an application written in C that uses GLib and exclusively targets Linux. Generally my experience has been that GLib's utilities are useful and generally make writing C easier compared to just using the C standard library. Then I noticed that g_strdup exists. Reading some documentation for strdup, I don't notice any obvious differences, apart from that g_strdup specifies that you can pass it NULL whereas strdup doesn't mention how it behaves in this scenario.
Given this information, is there any reason for me to use g_strdup over strdup?

If you know the value will never be NULL, there's no reason. glibc has replacements for most of the standard C library functions.

One more difference, a statement from C standard: "If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned and errno may be set". Not sure what error is being referred to. Out-of-memory? "errno may be set" suggests errno might not be set. The posix documentation which it's supposedly based on says the error is ENOMEM, see [https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html]. I'd stick with g_strdup.

You might find that there are non-POSIX systems without a native strdup(), but if Glib is present on the machine, g_strdup() will also be present.  If you don't think that'll be a problem, there's no particular reason to use g_strdup() rather than strdup(), but there's also little harm in using g_strdup() instead of strdup() if your software requires the presence of Glib.  If your code doesn't require Glib otherwise, use strdup().  And don't pass null pointers to either function.


Reading some documentation for strdup, I don't notice any obvious differences, apart from that g_strdup specifies that you can pass it NULL whereas strdup doesn't mention how it behaves in this scenario.

Their behaviour when NULL is passed as an input is one difference. The other key difference is:

g_strdup() will abort the program on a memory allocation failure, as per GLib’s general allocation policy. This is because it’s basically impossible to test all the error handling paths in anything other than a small program if you try and handle allocation failures; and allocation failures are very rare on systems with virtual memory and no pre-existing program bugs (such as allocation size calculation bugs).

Other than that, the two only exist because g_strdup() predates the standardised form of strdup() by a couple of decades.
Their implementations (g_strdup(), strdup()) are basically identical, modulo the differences in handling NULL input and allocation failure — they both measure the input string length, allocate space for it, then call memcpy() to copy the bytes to the new allocation. That’s unlikely to change.
One minor optimisation which g_strdup() has is that it optimises out the strlen() call for known-constant strings. So it will be immeasurably faster for some strings. There’s no reason the libc strdup() couldn’t do this in future too though.
Personally I’d choose g_strdup() to avoid having to explicitly deal with NULL input strings separately, or handle allocation failure, but the usefulness of that to you depends on your program’s policy about whether strings can be NULL in general, and how your program handles allocation failures.

I would use strdup because if you have NULL input strings, you have a big bug elsewhere in your program. Which is best addressed by actually fixing said bug, rather than adding extra bloat branches inside some completely unrelated string library function. Paranoid people who want to catch random null pointer bugs might want to add some assert during development, which is then stripped away at release.

As I said, it depends on your progam’s policy for whether strings are generally nullable. Many programs which use GLib explicitly allow a lot of strings to be NULL to indicate “this data is unset” or “this optional argument has not been provided”. Other programs may have a policy of strings generally being not-nullable though, and that’s fine. So the recommendation depends on the policy of the program in question.

In either case you shouldn't be passing null pointers to library functions. The library doesn't care and shouldn't need to care about your application-specific policy.

I feel you might be trying to die on a type-theoretic hill which doesn’t apply particularly well to C due to how it doesn’t encode nullability into the type system (there’s no distinction between pointers which are and are not permitted to be NULL). If you’ve written any non-trivial programs with GLib, I suspect you will find that the way g_strdup() operates is pragmatic. It avoids a lot of if (str != NULL) new_str = g_strdup (str); else new_str = NULL blocks in code.

The POSIX function strdup is included in C starting from the C23 Standard.
The functions g_strdup and strdup have different behaviors when a null pointer is passed as an argument. The function g_strdup in this case also returns a null pointer while the function strdup has undefined behavior in such a case. The function strdup returns a null pointer only if memory was not allocated for the duplicated string.
So it is much better to use the standard function strdup or the POSIX function strdup instead of the function g_strdup.
In any case it is always better to use standard functions instead of implementation-defined functions until you need a special behavior of a function which is absent in the corresponding standard function and that is very important.
